# Confusion with ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

For the second time I had a problem with values extracted from system calls using `ProcessBuilder`.

```
@org.junit.Test
public void test() {
    Process process = null;
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("QQ.exe");
    pb.directory(new File("D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tencent\\QQ\\Bin\\"));
    try {
        process = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

The result of above is: *"Cannot run program "QQ.exe" (in directory "D:\Program Files (x86)\Tencent\QQ\Bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"*

So what does the function of Process.dir()?
Somebody told me that the dir i specified is a working directory of running process - it doesn't help to find executable.
but the follow code could run rightly

```
@org.junit.Test
public void test() {
    Process process = null;
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","QQ.exe");
    pb.directory(new File("D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tencent\\QQ\\Bin\\"));
    try {
        process = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

The qq.exe is not in path。Who can tell me why? I am a chinese. I am not good at english, so Please excuse this wretched apology for my english.

Comment: Did you know Javadocs for Java Standard Edition are [available in Chinese](http://gceclub.sun.com.cn/Java_Docs/jdk6/html/zh_CN/api/index.html)? Or at least they were. It seems the site no longer exists :( Oracle has a lot of broken links on their websites.

Comment: http://gceclub.sun.com.cn/ this websit could not visit in china

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ProcessBuilder.directory(java.io.File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29) define the working directory of the process, not the "launch", so:

**case 1:** `QQ.exe` is started with working directory `D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tencent\\QQ\\Bin\\` but `QQ.exe` is not found (not in `%PATH%`)

**case 2:** `cmd.exe` is started with working directory `D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tencent\\QQ\\Bin\\` then `QQ.exe` is launched and found (cmd is in `%PATH%` and `QQ.exe` in current working dir)

We can assume that `ProcessBuilder` starts the process then perform a working directory change.